# How to escape a python interactive shell

Tags: python, ssh, server, command, escaping

I am trying to escape a python interactive shell within an ssh server without closing the ssh connection, using exit(), quit() ctrl D closes the ssh connection

Comment: Does your connection go directly into the interpreter or is there an other shell in between?

Comment: the python shell is opened within the ssh server, i need to escape the shell to actually get into the main dir of the ssh server –

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your connection is to a Linux/Unix server. If it's Windows, this won't help.

If you only close the python interpreter (ctrl-c for instance) it shouldn't close the SSH connection, since the python interpreter is running on top of the unix shell, which you are actually connected to.

The best way (or at least the easiest) to keep your SSH connection and keep any program running after you leave is to use a tool like `tmux` or `screen` (if your linux machine does not have `tmux` installed).

In order to do so, you can either start your program with `$ screen python` or start `screen` before you run anything, and it will start a `screen` session with bash running.

Then you can safely close the ssh connection, and, when you ssh back into the machine, use `screen -r` to return to where you leave.

Comment: Thanks for the response, am working with a ethical lab assessment with limited tools, also the python shell is opened within the ssh server, i need to escape the shell to actually get into the main dir of the ssh server

Comment: Are you actively starting the python shell? (As in you type `python` within the terminal) Or does it open automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily import the pty module

```
import pty
```

and then spawn a new bash shell "/bin/bash" with the module using

```
pty.spawn("/bin/bash")
```

Note: "bash" in this context can be changed depending on what shell is avaliable on the server which could be "sh", "dash" or any other type of unix compatible shell

Answer (score 0):

ssh -t

-t flag forces use of ptty. Control sequences will be sent directly to remote process

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).